# Error in is.na(output) || !is.character(output) : 'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)' in R when running xboost

Tags: r

When I am running

```
               xgboost(data = data.matrix(training.x[,-1]),

               label=as.numeric(as.character(training$bankruptcy.state)),

               eta = 0.2,

               max_depth = 2,

               nround=2,

               objective = "binary:logistic")
```

it appears the error:

> Error in is.na(output) || !is.character(output) :   'length = 3' in
> coercion to 'logical(1)'

My testing and training data set is like this:

```
set.seed(2021)
Partition <- createDataPartition(y = oneyearpred$bankruptcy.state, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
training <- oneyearpred[ Partition,]
testing <- oneyearpred[ -Partition,]
training.x <-model.matrix(bankruptcy.state~ ., data = training)
testing.x <-model.matrix(bankruptcy.state~ ., data = testing)
```

I have no idea what does this error mean and am wondering how to fix it